# IAM Cannot Access Launch Template

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am using the AWS Node SDK to try and use a launch template to launch an EC2 instance. In the web console for the same user I have access to the Launch Template ID, but in the Node API it tells me the Launch Template with ID does not exist:

version: aws-sdk@2.606.0

[image: screenshot of id in console]

Screenshot in AWS Console

[image: screenshot of id in my config file]

Screenshot in my config file

(I've blocked the last few characters for security but they are the same)

This is the Node

```js
         AWS = require('aws-sdk');
         AWS.config.update({region: global.settings.aws.region});

         let instanceParams = {
                LaunchTemplate: {
                    LaunchTemplateId: global.settings.aws.ltId
                }, 
                InstanceType: 't2.micro',
                MinCount: 1,
                MaxCount: 1
             };
             let instancePromise = new AWS.EC2().runInstances(instanceParams).promise();
             instancePromise.then(
               function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
               }).catch(
                 function(err) {
                 console.error(err, err.stack);
               });
```

This is the error the API returns:

InvalidLaunchTemplateId.NotFound: The specified launch template, with template ID lt-03969d13638b5XXXX, does not exist.
    at Request.extractError (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/ec2.js:50:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request. (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request. (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request. (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request. (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at callNextListener (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/ApplicationPath/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:307:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20) {
  message: 'The specified launch template, with template ID lt-03969d13638b5XXXX, does not exist.',
  code: 'InvalidLaunchTemplateId.NotFound',
  time: 2020-01-22T15:29:18.641Z,
  requestId: '16082702-49c0-4451-a3b7-570b930b5238',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 47.92654090836894
}

The IAM access includes both:

AmazonEC2FullAccess

AmazonEC2FullAccess

(The JSON are super long but I am happy to post those in here if needed)

My thought is that there is some permissioning error for the IAM but I can't determine what that might be. Thank you for the help and please let me know if there is any other clarity I can provide.

Comment: Are you making the API call to the correct region? Having insufficient permission does not hide things from view; choosing the wrong region does.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for bringing this up I do set the correct region and have edited my code to show that above.

Answer (score 1):

When you can see that a given AWS resource exists in the AWS console, but it is not returned by the awscli or SDK calls, (or vice-versa) then one of the following is likely the cause:

- you have queried the wrong region
- you have queried the wrong AWS account (your effective credentials are for a 2nd, different account)
- you have mis-typed the resource name/id
- your browser has cached results that no longer exist (refresh your browser)

Comment: thank you for this answer, I know that I am in the correct region, but I do think it is possible that I am in the wrong account. The confusing thing is that as far as I understand it I am using the same account to create the Launch Template as I am to access it in the API. I am just using the Root version in the console. This is not in the browser so it isn't related to cached results. Is the root version vs the API version of a user different?

Comment: Within your application (or from the awscli) run STS GetCallerIdentity (e.g. in the awscli it's `aws sts get-caller-identity`). It will tell you which AWS account number is associated with the active credentials. Then, within the AWS console, list your IAM users and verify the AWS account number is the same (it will be embedded in the User ARN e.g. `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/kai`). If you have no IAM users, create one temporarily.